# Im Unable to Write a txt File using fs on Nodejs ,can Somebody Help me?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

Im trying to write a txt File using Fs on Nodejs but I get the following error.

**call_and_retry_last allocation failed - process out of memory**

This is the code i am using :

```
UserPayment.find({} ,function (error , usersdata){
  count=usersdata.length;
  usersdata.forEach(function(user){
     sum+=user.Amount;
     fs.appendFile('unapec-appap.txt', 'D'+padding(user.Id,13)+user.IdType+padding(user.Account,15)+padding(user.Amount,20),function (err) {
        console.log(err);
     });
  });
  callback();
});
```

**UserPayment** is a call to a mongolab database using mongoose

Comment: `fs.appendFile` is `async`.

Answer (score 0):

You can `async` for appending line by line.

```
var async = require("async");

UserPayment.find({} ,function (error , usersdata){
  count=usersdata.length;
  async.each(usersdata, function(user, cb){
    sum+=user.Amount;

    fs.appendFile('unapec-appap.txt', 'D'+padding(user.Id,13)+user.IdType+padding(user.Account,15) + padding(user.Amount,20), function (err) {
        cb();
    });
  }, function(err){
    callback();
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never use Array.forEach function for large data. Also the forEach function blocks the code and in most cases won't work as expected with node, which is heavily based on non-blocking code(asynchronous code).

You could instead try 'async' library which has really useful functions for asynchronous javascript programming.

For this case, use the Async.Each function in a way like this:

```
async.each(arrayofusers, appendfilesfunction, function(err){
  // if any of the saves produced an error, err would equal that error
});
```

For your particular problem:

```
var async = require('async');

UserPayment.find({} ,function (error , usersdata){
    count=usersdata.length;

    async.each(userdata, function(user,next){
        sum+=user.Amount;
        fs.appendFile('unapec-appap.txt', 'D'+padding(user.Id,13)+user.IdType+padding(user.Account,15)+padding(user.Amount,20)
                      ,function (err) {
                          if(err) return next(err); 
                          next();
         });
    }, function(err){
        if(err) console.log(err); // All errors will be handled here
    });


});
```